# advanced user simulation using Gatling

Tags: karate

I am trying to simulate a user scenario over an api using Gatling. I am a newbie to scala and gatling and would like to simulate a load scenario such that:
it starts with 0 users,
increase a load of 5 users in 10 seconds,
holds the user load for the next 10 seconds,
increase 5 more users over the next 10 seconds,
holds the user load for the next 10 seconds,
ramp down users from 10 to 0 over the next 10 seconds.

I am using karate feature files to define the api specifications.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by referring to the [Karate docs](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling) and then the [Gatling docs](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup/#open-model):

```
  setUp(
    create.inject(
      rampUsers(5) during (10 seconds),
      nothingFor(10 seconds),
      rampUsers(5) during (10 seconds),
      nothingFor(10 seconds),
      rampUsers(0) during(10 seconds)
    ).protocols(protocol)
  )
```

Comment: i tried to replicate the same steps, but the user count in gatling report shows a peak at only 1 user in the active users graph.

Comment: @MrBrownstone try different values. read the docs. there can be bugs in karate - so follow this process if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue